# How do I delete an unposted answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers

A few times, I've read a question and in typing an answer, I get the banner thingie that says that new answer(s) have been uploaded.  I click to see what has been answered already, and see that my answer will essentially be a duplicate of what just got uploaded (that darn fastest finger in the West beat me again).  I delete all the text in the answer box.  A span of time later, I load up the question to see the continuing discussion, and my half-answer is saved.  I think it's a great feature if I start an answer at work and then go home and load it on my home computer, but what if I decided that I won't post the answer I started typing?  Is there some way to kill that answer?  It seems an awful use of resources (I know, memory is cheap now) to hold onto half of an answer that will never finish.

Comment: Generally, don't worry about using site resources. If a feature causes problems it will be noticed on the back end and be recoded or removed to make it efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Manually clear saved question drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68957/manually-resetingdiscarding-saved-question-drafts)

From the top answer:

> Data for only one question is stored for you. If you navigate to another question and start answering, you will loose what was stored of your last answer. You don't even have to worry about it.

No great waste of space to hold at most one answer for each person I think.